# How to debug a CSS issue using React, TypeScript, and Parcel

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, parceljs

I am primarily a Java developer and I'm not 100% familiar with the technologies I'm working with here.

I have a React application written in TypeScript which gets run through a Parcel bundler prior to deployment. When I run the application for local testing on my dev machine, the spacing of checkboxes in the application looks great:

[image: checkboxes aligned well]

The problem is after I build the application and run it on production, the checkboxes are no longer properly aligned:

[image: checkboxes with less space below some of them]

I have managed to track it down to a difference in the CSS between local:

[image: screen shot of CSS in DevTools for my localhost]

and production:

[image: screen shot of CSS in DevTools for production]

If you notice, the production CSS has an extra `margin-bottom: 0px` in the top CSS file (`.css-1h4ws66`). This is my problem--it is overriding the `margin-bottom: 10px` in the `.css-lidh19` file and thus ruining the spacing.

My problem is that I have no idea where the 0px bottom margin is coming from. It doesn't appear to be defined in any of the styles in the application.

I realize this isn't enough information for anyone to be able to say "this is your problem; do that," but nevertheless I am interested in any ideas on how to investigate the issue.

Comment: One thing that is really odd to my mind is the fact that the Spring checkbox in my example is not affected by this; in fact, in all groups of checkboxes, the first one is fine, but all the rest have this bottom margin issue.

Comment: What is `*:not(style)` here? Seems like a strange selector. What's in your CSS rule for for that selector? Also, I have a hunch that parcel is compiling the CSS variable there and is transforming those margin start values into more standard margins. And it may not be doing that correctly for some reason?

Comment: It seems odd to me, too, and I'm not sure where it's coming from. The one place I can find it is in some minified json files that are created as part of the parcel build.

Comment: Correction, the minified json files mentioned in my last comment are in the .cache folder created when I run the application locally.

Comment: A solution could be to find your style 'margin-bottom:10px' if you know where it is, and to add '!important'

Comment: @Azu Thanks for the thought. Unfortunately, I tried finding that style and couldn't locate it either. My head is spinning just trying to figure out where all the CSS is coming from.

Comment: Okay, then into your CSS file do the same. Write '.css-lidh19{margin-bottom:10px;!important}'

Comment: @Azu I found it! The margin-bottom I was looking for was disguised in a chakra-ui `my` property. I was able to add `!important` there and the problem is solved. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help:) Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't find why there was a `margin-bottom: 0px` that caused the issue in the first place, but I managed to find the place where the 10px margin was defined and add `!important`, which resolved the issue.

For anyone dealing with chakra-ui, don't just look for properties `margin-bottom`, `marginBottom`, or even the shorthand `mb`. Also look for `my` properties, as they define both the top and bottom margins for a component.